# Failed to install cyipopt on Google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, ipopt, cyipopt

I want to install cyipopt on Google colab, but it seems like I failed. The ultimate goal is to make ipopt and cyipopt work with HSL ma86/ma97.

I know there are other ways to install.

1. Use apt-get
   By using the following command, it is possible to use cyipopt, but I cannot use HSL, for example ma97. The following is the case that I faced.
   [Cannot load HSL for IPOPT in Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74777931/cannot-load-hsl-for-ipopt-in-google-colab)

```
!apt-get install coinor-libipopt-dev
!pip install cyipopt
```

2. Use conda environment
   By following detailed instructions, it is possible to set conda environments and simply use "conda install cyipopt". However, I need to use GPU acceleration using Jax, so I'm not considering it as an option for me.

On Google colab, I installed IPOPT and cyipopt with the following process.

1. install ipopt

```
# Clone IPOPT
!git clone https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt.git

# Install IPOPT
%cd /content/Ipopt/
!mkdir ./build
%cd /content/Ipopt/build
!/content/Ipopt/configure
!make
!sudo make install
%cd /content/
```

2. set path

```
import os
os.environ['PKG_CONFIG_PATH'] = '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/'
os.environ['PATH'] += ':/usr/local/bin'
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] += ':/usr/local/lib'
```

3. install cyipopt

```
!pip install cyipopt
```

4. import cyipopt

```
import cyipopt
from cyipopt import minimize_ipopt
from scipy.optimize import rosen, rosen_der
import numpy as np
```

The following is my code on Google colab.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1a5v-L0q-JCAMcptTzEGodvTUcnkNN9sR?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully installed cyipopt in Google Colab. Just run the below 2 lines:

```
!apt install build-essential pkg-config python3-pip python3-dev cython3 python3-numpy coinor-libipopt1v5 coinor-libipopt-dev

!pip install cyipopt
```